# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) passing parameter into helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, helper

```
module ProfilesHelper
  def accept (invites)
    invite=invites.find(id: '1')
    invite.accept= '1'
    invite.save
  end
end
```

The user needs to click a button to accept or deny an invitation they have received. I created this helper method, it's suppose to find the user's invite and then set it's accept boolean to 1. But I get "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

Views:

```
<% @invites.each do |invite| %>
  <%= link_to "Accept", accept(invite) %> 
<% end %>
```

How do I pass the invite object into the accept helper?

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: You're also passing a single `invite` to the helper but then calling a method on it as it were an array or an activerecord relation

Comment: That makes sense, how do I make sure I only call one invite from method?

Comment: I removed the     invite=invites.find(id: '1')
line, as a means of only modifying that one entry, but it did not work

Comment: Did you get an error or something? You also have to change the method parameter to just `invite`

Comment: yes same error as before

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of helpers. With the way you're using this code, the invite will be accepted when the page is viewed, not when the link is clicked.

Helpers are there to help you lay out the page. Either by abstracting logic away from the view, decorating things, formatting numbers into currency, or a million other things. They are not for handling requests.

You shouldn't be using standard `GET` requests (an anchor tag) to make changes to your data set. They should come via `PUT`, `PATCH`, `POST`, `DELETE` requests.

What you need here is to either use a `button` element, or change your link to submit the request using a `PUT` or `PATCH` verb. Then, using a suitable route to receive the request to accept the invite, add an action to your controller to handle this request.

Then in your controller you can do something like this:

```
def accept_invite
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
  @invite.accept!
end
```

Which allows you to move the business logic of handling that acceptance into the model:

```
class Invite
  def accept!
    accept = true
    save
    # You might want to do other things here, like email them a confirmation etc.
  end
end
```

This way, your controller can worry about just handling the request, and the model can worry about how to handle actually accepting an invite.

Comment: I just realised there was a major error in my implementation, I am altering it now

Comment: And what is the syntax to call it from view?  <%= button_to "Accept", invite.invites.accept_invite %>?

Comment: Something like `<%= button_to 'Accept', accept_invite_path(invite) %>`. You need to be using the path to the controller action that handles the acceptance request.

Comment: Okay, it seems to get the correct invite, but I get "No route matches [POST]", My routes are "  resources :accept_invite" Checking the rails routes accept_invite does have a put, and place  requests (no POST)

Comment: Then you need to tell `button_to` what `:method` to use. Check the documentation and it should list something along the lines of `button_to 'Label', action_path, method: :put`

Comment: Now, I get a "uninitialized constant AcceptInviteController"

Comment: I just realised something, I have accept_invite as it's own resource, does accept_invite have to be a resource belonging to the invite resource (like with a do collection?) Or else how does the routes know which class it's getting accept_invite from?

Comment: These questions are now quite far removed from the initial issue you experienced. You'd be best off to create a new question.

Comment: Well, I can't create a new question